# how to loop in a row with each column increasing by 1 and so on

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops

I have homework to make a program to display several data with the following display:

```
#
#$
#$%
#$%#
#$%#$
#$%#$%
```

I had tried, but it looks so weird, I don't know what else to do, I'm stuck, this is my code :

```js
let str = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  str += '#';
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    str += '$';
    for (let k = 1; k < i; k++) {
      str += '%';
      for (let k = 1; k < i; k++) {
        str += '#';
      }
    }
  }
  str += backpace = '\n';
}
console.log(str);
```

my code does not display what I expect, I hope sombody can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's your homework. Do not use that many loops, it is not necessary. Just store
 the current line and concat next char in next loopcycle.

```js
const source = '#$%';
let str = '';
let output = '';

for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  str += source[i % source.length];
  output += str + '\n';
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: oww i see, thank you man, Homework given by my teacher is not the same as what is taught :(, stackoverflow now is my online teacher :D

Answer (score 1):

You just need two loops, one for the rows, and one for the columns. The loop for the columns only has to iterate to the current row number, e.g. for the third row, the column loop has to iterate three times.

```
  for(let col = 0; col <= row; col++)
```

To get the character to be displayed at a certain column you could take a string of the characters to repeatedly display, e.g. `"#$%"`, then access the col-th character in that string. With the modulo operator you can then make sure that col 3 results in the first char to be taken, col 4 the second and so on:

```
 "#$%"[col % 3] // 0 => "#", 1 => "$", 2 => "%", 3 => "#", ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Way too many loops, you only need 2 loops

```js
    let dict = ["#", "$", "%"]; // available symbols in order
    let str = ''; // final string
    let linesToRender = 6; // number of lines to render

    for (let line = 0; line < linesToRender ; line++) {
      // line loop
      for (let col = 0; col <= line; col++) {
        // column loop ( from 0 to line number )
        str += dict[col % dict.length]
      }
      str += "\n";
    }
    console.log(str);
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions